# QuickSort Tester Debugging

Tags: java

I have the following code for 4 kinds of partition method for `quickSort`. Right now, if I run the code the performance of various partitions are as follows

1. partition0 performance is 1877,
2. partition2 is 781,
3. partition3 674,
4. partition4 is around 595.

Numbers may vary for different machines and different time.  And I can't tell the bugs with each partition right now and I have few questions:

1. I noticed the only difference between partition0 and partition1 is that the while loop's condition: one has <= and the other one has <. But when I changed the first <= to <, the performance doesn't change. 2. what is do{ }  while(some condition). Is it same as the normally used while loop?
2. I noticed the only difference between `partition0` and `partition1` is that the `while` loop's condition: one has `<=` and the other one has `<`. But when I changed the first `<=` to `<`, the performance doesn't change.
3. what is `do{ }  while(some condition)`. Is it same as the normally used while loop?

---

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class QuickSortTester {
static private Random rand = new Random(0);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arraySize = 1000;

    Integer[] list;

    long start, end;

    list = generateSortedIntegerArray(arraySize);
    // list = generateRandomIntegerArray(arraySize);
    System.out.printf("\n%15d", arraySize);

    start = System.nanoTime();
    sort(list, 0);
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf("\t%15d", (end - start) / 1000);
    if (!isSorted(list))
        System.out.printf("Not sorted - problems!");

    System.out.println();

    list = generateSortedIntegerArray(arraySize);
    // list = generateRandomIntegerArray(arraySize);
    System.out.printf("\n%15d", arraySize);

    start = System.nanoTime();
    sort(list, 1);
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf("\t%15d", (end - start) / 1000);
    if (!isSorted(list))
        System.out.printf("Not sorted - problems!");

    System.out.println();
    list = generateSortedIntegerArray(arraySize);
    // list = generateRandomIntegerArray(arraySize);
    System.out.printf("\n%15d", arraySize);

    start = System.nanoTime();
    sort(list, 2);
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf("\t%15d", (end - start) / 1000);
    if (!isSorted(list))
        System.out.printf("Not sorted - problems!");

    System.out.println();
    list = generateSortedIntegerArray(arraySize);
    //list = generateRandomIntegerArray(arraySize);
    System.out.printf("\n%15d", arraySize);

    start = System.nanoTime();
    sort(list, 3);
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf("\t%15d", (end - start) / 1000);
    if (!isSorted(list))
        System.out.printf("Not sorted - problems!");

}


public static <E extends Comparable<E>> boolean isSorted(E[] list) {
    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i - 1].compareTo(list[i]) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


public static Integer[] generateRandomIntegerArray(int size) {
    Integer list[] = new Integer[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        // list[i] = rand.nextInt(10); //range from zero to number - 1
        list[i] = rand.nextInt(); // unlimited range
    return list;
}

public static Integer[] generateSortedIntegerArray(int size) {
    Integer list[] = generateRandomIntegerArray(size);
    Arrays.sort(list);
    return list;
}

public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void sort(E[] list, int version) {
    quickSort(list, 0, list.length - 1, version);
}

private static <E extends Comparable<E>> void quickSort(E[] list, int first, int last, int version) {
    if (last > first) {
        int pivotIndex;
        if (version == 0)
            pivotIndex = partition0(list, first, last);
        else if (version == 1)
            pivotIndex = partition1(list, first, last);
        else if (version == 2)
            pivotIndex = partition2(list, first, last);
        else
            pivotIndex = partition3(list, first, last);
        quickSort(list, first, pivotIndex - 1, version);
        quickSort(list, pivotIndex + 1, last, version);
    }
}

private static <E extends Comparable<E>> int partition0(E[] list, int first, int last) {
    int pivotIndex = (first + last) / 2;
    E pivot = list[pivotIndex]; // Choose the first element as the pivot
    swap(list, last, pivotIndex);
    pivotIndex = last;
    last--;
    while (last >= first) {
        // Search forward from left
        while (first <= last && list[first].compareTo(pivot) < 0) //problem
            first++;
        // Search backward from right
        while (first <= last && list[last].compareTo(pivot) >= 0)
            last--;

        // Swap two elements in the list
        if (last > first) {
            swap(list, first, last);
            first++;
            last--;
        }
    }
    swap(list, pivotIndex, first);

    return first;
}

private static <E extends Comparable<E>> int partition1(E[] list, int first, int last) {
    int pivotIndex = (first + last) / 2;
    E pivot = list[pivotIndex]; // Choose the first element as the pivot
    swap(list, last, pivotIndex);
    pivotIndex = last;
    last--;
    while (last >= first) {
        // Search forward from left
        while (first <= last && list[first].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
            first++;
        // Search backward from right
        while (first <= last && list[last].compareTo(pivot) >= 0)
            last--;

        // Swap two elements in the list
        if (last > first) {
            swap(list, first, last);
            first++;
            last--;
        }
    }
    swap(list, pivotIndex, first);

    return first;
}

private static <E extends Comparable<E>> int partition2(E[] list, int first, int last) {

    int pivotIndex = (first + last) / 2;

    E pivot = list[pivotIndex]; // Choose the first element as the pivot
    swap(list, last, pivotIndex);
    pivotIndex = last;
    last--;

    while (last > first) {
        // Search forward from left
        while (first <= last && list[first].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
            first++;
        // Search backward from right
        while (first <= last && list[last].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
            last--;

        // Swap two elements in the list
        if (last > first) {
            swap(list, first, last);
            first++;
            last--;
        }
    }
    swap(list, pivotIndex, first);

    return first;
}

private static <E extends Comparable<E>> int partition3(E[] list, int first, int last) {
    int pivotIndex = (first + last) / 2;
    E pivot = list[pivotIndex]; // Choose the first element as the pivot
    swap(list, last, pivotIndex);
    pivotIndex = last;
    last--;
    do {
        // Search forward from left
        while (first < last && list[first].compareTo(pivot) <= 0)
            first++;
        // Search backward from right
        while (first <= last && list[last].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
            last--;

        // Swap two elements in the list
        if (last >= first) {
            swap(list, first, last);
            first++;
            last--;
        }
    } while (last > first);

    swap(list, pivotIndex, first);

    return first;
}

private static <E> void swap(E[] list, int index1, int index2) {
    E tmp = list[index1];
    list[index1] = list[index2];
    list[index2] = tmp;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I am not a 100% sure, but I believe that is because last and first are used to check if the index from left and right have met. If so the swap will not occur and if first and last ane equal, when it gets to the if statement that does the swap will not occur.
2. do-while loop it is like a while loop, the difference is that it will execute always 1 time, no matter if the statement is true or false. Then it will execute the block like a normal while loop or not depending on the boolean condition you set for it.

More information about do-while loop: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

In your code:

```
do {
        // Search forward from left
        while (first < last && list[first].compareTo(pivot) <= 0)
            first++;
        // Search backward from right
        while (first <= last && list[last].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
            last--;

        // Swap two elements in the list
        if (last >= first) {
            swap(list, first, last);
            first++;
            last--;
        }
    } while (last > first);
```

It will always execute the inside of do first, then if last > first, will keep executing until the statement is false.